# Unity objects bend around forcefield

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I want to achieve this image below where it looks like the towers are being influenced by forcefield. [image: collapse]

It looks simple, right?

```
GameObject towers = GameObject.Find("towers");
GameObject ball = GameObject.Find ("ball");

foreach (Transform tower in towers.transform) {
    Vector3 heading = ball.transform.position - tower.position;
    float distance = heading.magnitude;
    Vector3 direction = heading.normalized;
    Vector3 newDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(ball.transform.position, heading, 1, 0.0F);
    tower.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDir);
    //Debug.DrawRay(ball.transform.position, newDir, Color.red);
}
```

This is the result:

[image: collapse result]

The towers in the back are decent but the front is falling in the wrong direction. What happened? Also, is there a way to control how much influence the towers bend depending on the distance from the ball to the tower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses an AnimationCurve to control the rotation angle of your towers according to the distance between them and your ball.

My animation curve has two keys :

1. (0, 90) // Meaning the tower will be rotated 90° when they are 0 units from the ball
2. (10, 0) // Meaning the tower will be rotated 0° when they are 10 units from the ball

```cs
public AnimationCurve effect;
private GameObject towers ;
private GameObject ball ;

private void Start()
{
    towers = GameObject.Find("towers");
    ball = GameObject.Find ("ball");
}

private void Update()
{
    foreach (Transform tower in towers.transform)
    {
        Vector3 direction = (ball.position - tower.position);
        Vector3 rotationAxis = Vector3.Cross( direction.normalized, Vector3.up );
        float angle = effect.Evaluate( direction.magnitude ) ;
        tower.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis( angle, rotationAxis );
        // If you want your towers to look at your ball :
        // tower.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation( direction ) * Quaternion.Euler( -angle, 0, 0 );
    }
}
```

Comment: That's is awesome! I didn't know I could use AnimationCurve like that. The code snippet makes the towers rotate around the ball instead of getting ran over. It's like they're trying to avoid touching the ball. Do you have an idea of how to achieve that?

Comment: I thought it was the intended behaviour. In the `foreach` loop, you will find two ways to rotate the towers, maybe, the 2nd one is the way you want tthe towers to rotate. You can adjust the animation curve to manage the rotation angle of the towers.

Comment: Good enough. I can live with it.